# How to hide subcategories into hover menu

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to hide the sub categories into menu.
How can I do?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the module menu there is no options to hide subcategories. you have to use css :

```
#block_top_menu ul li li ul {display:none!important;}
```